# would like to be able to walk into one direction while looking into another

Tags: camera

it's about to record camera-style movement (keyframes) while walking around (using the walk navigation in a blender scene). i can't figure out a way to achieve this. many games (for example) have the feature to press the 'Alt' key while walking with wasd in order to just turn the head (pov).

is there a way to achieve this? or isn't it possible while using walk/fly navigation? i'm very new to all this.

it would make simulating walking around with camera much much easier and i remember watching a youtube video where somebody attached a camera to a cube using the cube to move (walk with wasd keys) while being able to rotate the camera with mouse input.

edit: more description

Comment: in blender you can walk around and while that recording keyframes. that's what i want to do. i want to be able to move the direction of the camera in another direction than i'm walking. no idea what you mean by "i haven't anything yet". there's nothing to show. i create plane and i walk and i record but i always have to record the way i am walking to. my question is clear.